# Numpy - applying functions over sub arrays in N-D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a 5-dimensional numpy array. I want to apply a transformation over the sub-arrays within the array in the way shown below

```
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        arr[i, :, j, :, :] = fn(arr[i, :, j, :, :], *args)
```

The function (fn) return an array that is of same shape as the input

Is there a better way to do this ? How could I possibly vectorize this in an efficient way ?

Comment: That depends on the function

Comment: As long as your function can only work with the 3d input, there isn't much you can change.  The details of the iteration method don't make much of a difference, especially if `fn` is not trivial.  Now if you can compile the function, and make it much faster, then the iteration method matters, but not as long as it is a Python function that has to be called one for each of those N*M cases.

Comment: If the function is vectorizable, then you can probably get rid of loop. Could you provide us the function so we can help better?